# How to clear a SAPUI5 input field with only value help input allowed?

Tags: sapui5

my SAPUI5 app has an [input](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.Input.html#constructor) field where the valid values must be obtained through a value help:

```
<Input showValueHelp="true" valueHelpOnly="true"
                           valueHelpRequest="onValueHelpRequest"
                           value="{myModel>/myField}"
```

The value help is realized with a [SelectDialog](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.SelectDialog.html), where the only options are

1. choose one or
2. cancel

The problem is now the following flow:

1. User opens value help dialog to choose one item and presses *Confirm*
2. Input field now displays chosen value
3. User wants to clear the input, because it's optional

Unfortunately,

1. `sap.m.Input` doesn't provide a clear button
2. `sap.m.SelectDialog` doesn't provide the possibility to add a custom button like *Clear*
3. The input is layed out in a SimpleForm with 2 columns, labels and input fields, so it would be hard to add a clear button
4. The Gateway entity set which feeds the value help dialog list doesn't have a totally empty line
5. I don't like the workaround to switch the SelectDialog to [multiSelect](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.SelectDialog.html#getMultiSelect) just for the purpose that the user can choose "one or none". I also think it would be hard to explain to the user "if you want to remove the value, hold the control key and click on the previously selected item again".

Any ideas out there how to easily implement a clear button or something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
valueHelpOnly="false"
```

// with this user can either fill by F4 (assisted input) or by typing input..
and if you want to clear you can add a button  and set the value to null

```
oInput.setValue("");
```

Comment: 1. `valueHelpOnly="false"` is not possible as the user must not enter invalid data. 2. I have followed your second advice: `<HBox><Input/><Button press="clearInput"/></HBox>`